# ZeroMQ permanent PULL socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, zeromq, distributed-system, pyzmq

I’ve been using a `PUSH/PULL` pattern in an application and it works as expected except when I switch off abruptly the computer or remove the ethernet cable in the `PULL`-side.

The `PUSH`-side keeps working with other `PULL`-sockets, but maintains switched off socket as if still were alive.

I have modified TCP-parameters (interval, count...) without results.

Is it possible to avoid this connection even when the host computer is switched off or the ethernet cable removed?

EDIT:

This is a small test i've made

server.py

```
import zmq
import time

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVHWM, 1)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SNDHWM, 1)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.IMMEDIATE, 1)
print(socket.sndtimeo)
socket.sndtimeo = 0

socket.setsockopt(zmq.TCP_KEEPALIVE,1)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.TCP_KEEPALIVE_CNT,1)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.TCP_KEEPALIVE_IDLE,1)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.TCP_KEEPALIVE_INTVL,1)
socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')
count= 0
while True:
    print('Sending', count)
    try:
        socket.send(str(count).encode('utf-8'), zmq.NOBLOCK)
        count+= 1
        print('Ok')
    except zmq.error.Again:
        print('Error')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

client.py

```
import zmq
import time
import sys
#from common import time_utils

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
server = '127.0.0.1:5555'
try:
    server = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    pass
socket.setsockopt(zmq.TCP_KEEPALIVE,1)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.TCP_KEEPALIVE_CNT,1)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.TCP_KEEPALIVE_IDLE,1)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.TCP_KEEPALIVE_INTVL,1)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.RCVHWM, 1)
socket.connect(server)
while True:
#  Wait for next request from client
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received request: ", message)
```

Running one instance of the server and 2 clients (one in the same machine that runs the server and one in other computer). Removing the ethernet cable of the second computer results in that the server keeps sending messages to the second client for a while.

As you can see I have tested all `setsockopt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the ZMTP ping/pong options. These should detect the connection being lost as it runs at a higher level than the TCP sockets (which can be held open after the connection is down)

`ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_IVL, ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT and ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_TTL`

http://api.zeromq.org/4-3:zmq-setsockopt

Answer (score 2):

> **Q** : *Is it **possible to avoid this** connection even when the host Computer is switched off?*

For connection-oriented transport-classes, you may `.setsockopt( zmq.IMMEDIATE, 1 )` so as to avoid storing outgoing messages on the `PUSH`-side for a dead connection.

As an additional step, one may add another, explicit `ACK/NACK` signalling-flow, that may help independently and explicitly detect any such event of a dead-man not responding on the `ACK/NACK`-loop(s).

Comment: I've tested it that parametter but still does not work as expected. Thx